# LineChart performance decrease over time

Tags: java, multithreading, performance, javafx-2, javafx-8

So we're working on an signal processing application, there's a specific type of hardware in the PC and a C driver communicating with it. 
The application frontend/gui is written in JavaFX. We're having some issues with the JavaFX LineChart, we're measuring electrical signal frequency and trying to plot it on the aforementioned LineChart.

The measurements are running in a loop until 1000 samples are gathered, we've been testing with 100Hz signal, which means that it takes 10s to get these 1000 samples.

There's a separate 'LineChart' thread running and checking (every 10ms) whether there are new samples available, if so these are added to the LineChart, if the measurement thread is finished the LineChart thread resets the LineChart (clears the series data) and the process starts over.

Every thing is running fine for first ~20 min, after which it seems that the LineChart 'slows down', it looks as if the drawing is not as fast/dynamic as in the beginning.

We've checked pretty much everything we could in the application and found nothing, so we've created a separate project which only has the LineChart and a thread that adds samples to the chart every 10ms (up to 1000 samples). We've observed the same behavior, here's how it's done:

```
        Thread t = new Thread(new Runnable() {
        @Override
        public void run() {

            int iteration = 0;
            long start = 0;
            long stop = 0;

            while (run) {

                CountDownLatch latch = new CountDownLatch(1);
                start = System.currentTimeMillis();

                for (int i = 0; i < 1001; i++) {
                    double ran = random(50, 105);
                    final int c = i;

                    Platform.runLater(() -> {
                        series.getData().add(new XYChart.Data<>(c, ran));

                        if (c == 1000) {
                            System.out.print("Points:  " + series.getData().size());
                            series.getData().clear();

                            latch.countDown();
                        }
                    });

                    try {
                        Thread.sleep(10);
                    } catch (InterruptedException e) {
                        e.printStackTrace();
                    }
                }
                iteration++;
                stop = System.currentTimeMillis();

                try {
                    latch.await();
                } catch (InterruptedException e) {}

                System.out.println(", Iteration : " + iteration + ", elapsed: " + (stop - start) + " [ms]");
            }
        }
    });
```

What are we missing here? Why is the performance dropping after ~30-45 min in above example? Any ideas?

The above piece of code was run for 8h, each time all points were added to the Chart, the 'drawing time' was comparable (between 10100ms and 10350ms).

Comment: You say _We've observed the same behavior_ and _each time all points were added to the Chart, the 'drawing time' was comparable_ . Shouldn't there be a slowdown so the times aren't all the same?  Also, just an idea, in a stock market chart I can remove data and it never slows down.  Maybe `if (c > 1000) series.getData().remove(0,500)`;

Comment: That's I thought, and that's why I started measuring this time, which to my surprise was at comparable levels each iteration. Are you running your chart in a loop? May I ask with which parameters? How many points, what's the refresh rate, for how long were you running it?

Comment: I get data from a socket, 3hz max, a few 1000 points until I remove old ones.  I don't use it any more as I want more points but it would work for 8 hrs.  I still don't understand if the code example is slowing down for you.  If the times are the same, it's not slowing down.

Comment: Yeah well i know it's odd, the time remains nearly constant, whereas looking at the plot it looks as if it's slower than after first start even though each time all points are added as expected.

Comment: Please provide a SSCCE that demonstrates the problem.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found the reason, it was lack of hardware acceleration on Linux Platforms where AMD GFX cards where installed. Oracle did not provide hardware support so JavaFX was falling back to some crappy one resulting in performance decay. The piece of code from original post works no problem on Win machines or Linux machines with Nvidia cards BUT not on Linux with AMD cards. On Linux with amd cards you have to manually enforce software acceleration (as opposed to the default one).

Answer (score 0):

You don't have anything wrong with the code that I can see, but, you keep adding to the series. I don't think that this is an issue with the code, but it's the machine trying to keep up and manage ALL the points you have, you said 1000 in 10s, that means that after 20 mins, you have 120,000 points in storage, being managed, and plotted. Assuming that you record to the tenths place, thats a TON of storage, and more likely than not, you're seeing the processing slow down with all that info. Simply put, the machine can't handle it.

Comment: Thanks for the input, that's unfortunately not it. Each time 1000th sample is added to the chart, the chart series is cleared as you see in the if block.

Comment: in that case, I'm not too sure, maybe it's allotted the storage for the 120,000 points, 100 points at a time. Sometimes java gets a little sticky. I don't know what causes it, or why it does this, but it occasionally happens.

Comment: We;re monitoring memory consumption, all looks good, so does CPU

Comment: hmm, this must be one of those instances where java gets sticky, I don't know what causes it, but something messes up java's cleanup procedure, you might have that

Answer (score 0):

This is an older question, but in case anyone stumbles across it looking for performance problems, there is a huge hit here in the way data is added to the series.
Points should be added to a series all at once when possible, rather than individually.

In the case of the above example, if the code collected all encountered data points into a list, and then added to the entire list to the series using an addAll call, the performance would increase. The frequency of the addAll call can be set based on trial and error for aesthetic performance, but the hertz a user can see is much less than the hertz the Platform.RunLater is trying to update.

Comment: Nope. Nothing to do with that. I found the reason, it was lack of hardware acceleration on Linux Platforms where AMD GFX cards where installed. Oracle did not provide hardware support so JavaFX was falling back to some crappy one resulting in performance decay. The piece of code from original post works no problem on Win machines or Linux machines with Nvidia cards BUT not on Linux with AMD cards. On Linux with amd cards you have to manually enforce software acceleration (as opposed to the default one).

Comment: @Stugal as you are still around, you might consider posting this comment as an answer :)